# How to filter the JSON array in psql using prisma

Tags: node.js, psql, prisma

my table is `job_roles`. the table contains `cities Json  @map("citites")`

the cities have

```
[
  {
    "id": "6364ed9ae0338a14ae72eb8d",
    "name": "Bengaluru"
  },
  {
    "id": "6364edafe0338a14ae7356b8",
    "name": "Chennai"
  },
  {
    "id": "6364eda6e0338a14ae73259e",
    "name": "Mumbai"
  }
]
```

i want `{name:"Mumbai"}`

now i using `{ cities: { array_contains: [{ name: city }] } }` query in
`await prisma.jobRoles.aggregate` function.

the `city` from `req.body`

it take more then 40 seconds
how to solve it?